# Executing function on objects of name 'i' within for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am still pretty new to R and very new to for-loops and functions, but I searched quite a bit on stackoverflow and couldn't find an answer to this question. So here we go.

I'm trying to create a script that will (1) read in multiple .csv files and (2) apply a function to strip twitter handles from urls in and do some other things to these files. I have developed script for these two tasks separately, so I know that most of my code works, but something goes wrong when I try to combine them. I prepare for doing so using the following code:

```
# specify directory for your files and replace 'file' with the first, unique part of the
# files you would like to import
mypath <- "~/Users/you/data/"
mypattern <- "file+.*csv"

# Get a list of the files
file_list <- list.files(path = mypath,
                        pattern = mypattern)

# List of names to be given to data frames
data_names <- str_match(file_list, "(.*?)\\.")[,2]

# Define function for preparing datasets
handlestripper <- function(data){
  data$handle <- str_match(data$URL, "com/(.*?)/status")[,2]
  data$rank <- c(1:500)
  names(data) <- c("dateGMT", "url", "tweet", "twitterid", "rank")
  data <- data[,c(4, 1:3, 5)]
}
```

That all works fine. The problem comes when I try to execute the function `handlestripper()` within the for-loop.

```
# Read in data
for(i in data_names){
  filepath <- file.path(mypath, paste(i, ".csv", sep = ""))
  assign(i, read.delim(filepath, colClasses = "character", sep = ","))
  i <- handlestripper(i)
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error: `Error in data$URL : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. I know that this means that my function is being applied to the string I called from within the vector `data_names`, but I don't know how to tell R that, in this last line of my for-loop, I want the function applied to the *objects* of name *i* that I just created using the assign command, rather than to *i* itself.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that your `assign` call doesn't throw an error. More generally, why not loop over an index instead of the values?

Comment: You are messing with the loop index, which is an R object. Looks like bad practice. Might be easier to use `sapply`.

Comment: `get` may solve the problem... as in `handlestripper(get(i))`... but i think DWin and joran point out some larger issues that should be resolved!

Comment: @joran How would I go about doing that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had in mind something like `for (i in seq_along(data_names))` and then you'd access the appropriate element via `data_names[i]`. But `sapply` would be another good option. More generally, I would recommend that you avoid using `assign`.

Comment: @joran @DWin I tried `(i in seq_along(data_names))` with `data_names[i] <- handlestripper(data_names[i])` as the final line, but now I am getting a new error: `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/you/data//1.csv': No such file or directory`. How might I use `sapply` and avoid using `assign`? I'm sure that your directions would be clear to someone better at R, but I'm still new. Do I have to make a list of dataframes in order to use `sapply` on them?

Comment: Just change the last two lines to use a temporary variable: `tmp <- read... ; assign(i, handlestripper(tmp))`. You should make as few `get` and `assign` calls as you can, but there's nothing wrong with indexing your loop with names as you are doing (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Great! In that case, I guess I'll post it as an answer, then. I'll delete or amend it if these other commenters find something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, you can change this:

```
assign(i, read.delim(filepath, colClasses = "character", sep = ","))
i <- handlestripper(i)
```

to

```
tmp <- read.delim(filepath, colClasses = "character", sep = ",")
assign(i, handlestripper(tmp))
```

I think you should make as few `get` and `assign` calls as you can, but there's nothing wrong with indexing your loop with names as you are doing. I do it all the time, anyway.

Comment: Almost - the last line of my code now reads `assign(i, handlestripper(tmp))` so that the loop output is a dataframe of name i.

Comment: Oops, I mis-copied my own suggestion! :) Thanks for pointing it out.